# What question has the most deleted answers?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers

I noticed that the question [Is Amy Pond Clara's grandmother?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/47401/51226) has a staggering eight deleted answers.

Do any of the site's questions have more than that?

Answer (score 10):

[Technically](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/533885/questions-with-most-deleted-answers) it's a tie between two deleted questions (10k+ only):

- [What are some good SF books by authors not generally known for science fiction?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/217/31051)
- [What works feature humans gaining immortality and its effects?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/687/31051)

Both of which have 24 deleted answers. But something tells me that isn't what you meant, so:

### [Non-deleted questions with most deleted answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/533886/non-deleted-questions-with-most-deleted-answers)

Technically, the winner is [How was Ronan able to handle the Infinity stone without being destroyed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/99767/31051), with 11 deleted answers. As amaranth notes in comments, however, this is a somewhat degenerate case; all 11 deleted answers spawned from a single, confused (possibly troll-y) user.

If you want to exclude that nonsense, then we have a three-way tie between:

- [Where were the Avengers during Iron Man 3?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/35318/31051)
- [Why did Douglas Adams pick 42 as the ultimate answer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/310/31051)
- [How much money did Harry Potter have?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12260/31051)

All of which have ten deleted answers.

In total there are 8 (non-deleted) questions with more than 8 deleted answers, at time of writing:

- [How was Ronan able to handle the Infinity stone without being destroyed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/99767/31051) (11, though with the oddity noted above)
- [Where were the Avengers during Iron Man 3?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/35318/31051) (10)
- [Why did Douglas Adams pick 42 as the ultimate answer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/310/31051) (10)
- [How much money did Harry Potter have?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12260/31051) (10)
- [How does human-robot sex work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/19323/31051) (9)
- [Is it true that The Doctor can only regenerate 12 times?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/809/31051) (9)
- [After Star Trek: The Next Generation, can I skip to Voyager without watching Deep Space Nine and not get spoiled?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1566/31051) (9)
- [How did Doomsday kill Superman?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9011/31051) (9)

Comment: "How does human-robot sex work?" ... erm :-/

Comment: @Randal'Thor - [It works very well indeed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuVQWech6N0)

Comment: @jason - you can probably filter out "answers deleted as part of question's deletion" by checking delete date/time of answer to be different than that of question (probably corrected by precision of epsilon seconds to account for probable deletion speed slowness)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile Yes, I think that could be done. But I think it would complicate the query, and it wouldn't really be any more performant - I'd still need to join against the `PostsWithDeleted` table in that scenario, but the exclusion clause would be more complicated

Answer (score 2):

[Why could Quirrell tolerate Harry's touch at the beginning of Philosopher's Stone?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25182/why-could-quirrell-tolerate-harrys-touch-at-the-beginning-of-philosophers-ston) is an extant question with fifteen deleted answers. That surpasses any of the examples of extant questions mentioned in [the other answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10122/100430).